# Number of equivalence relations on a finite set

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations, set-partition

I need a hint for computing the number of ways in which all the equivalent classes on a set of $n$ elements can be realized. For example, if the set has 2 elements ${a,b}$, then there are 2 possible partitions: either a and b are related or not.

Comment: Do you mean the number of equivalence **relations**? (The maximum number of equivalent classes is $n$, which appears if you take equality as your equivalence relation.)

Comment: You are right. I mean if you have 3 equivalent classes, in how many ways can they be realized. I edited the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An equivalence relation uniquely corresponds to a partition of the base set. For a fixed size $n$ of the base set, the number of such partitions is known as the *Bell number* $B_n$, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_numbers) and the [Online encyclopedia of integer sequences](https://oeis.org/A000110).

The first Bell numbers are $$1, 1, 2, 5, 15, 52, 203, 877, 4140, 21147, 115975, \ldots$$
The numbers are growing rapidly. Also, note that no simple closed formula for $B_n$ is known.

Comment: I edited the question. I got it wrong at first. Thank you.

Comment: @saadtaame: ok. So I guess my post exactly answers your question. I'll edit to give some more details.

Comment: Isn't no. of partitions of a 2-element set = 3? {{a}}, {{b}}, {{a, b}}. How does the Bell number show 2 instead?

Comment: @Happy: Neither $\{\{a\}\}$ nor $\{\{b\}\}$ is a partition of $\{a,b\}$. The two partitions of $\{a,b\}$ are given by $\{\{a\},\{b\}\}$ and $\{\{a,b\}\}$.

Comment: Oh, right, I get it now. Thanks for that clarification.

Answer (score 7):

The number of ways of splitting a set of $n$ elements into $k$ classes is counted by the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number), the total number of equivalence relations is the $n$-th [Bell number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

Answer (score 2):

Every equivalence relation in a set induce a partition of that set into non-empty blocs and vice versa every set partition defines a equivalence relation on that set. Number of set partitions i.e number of equivalence relations on a n-set is called Bell number $B_n$.