# What are the number of possible partitions of a set containing n elements?

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

This question rises immediately if we try to enumerate the number of possible equivalence relations on a set with n elements.

Answer (score 1):

The number of partitions of a finite set is counted by Bell numbers, summing up Stirling numbers. See a similar question here: [Number of equivalence relations on a finite set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322738/number-of-equivalence-relations-on-a-finite-set)